# Using * in regex as a value to lookup

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of a string `***deal***` When I use the following code I receive a `Quantifier {x,y} following nothing` error.

```
var regex = new RegExp('***deal***', 'g');
Content=Content.replace(regex, DEAL);
```

Can anyone fill me in how I'm supposed to get past the error?

As a note I'm using Server Side Javascript with a .NET backend.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is a metacharacter (meaning "zero or more of the preceding token", and there is nothing preceding the `*`s in your regex, hence the error message) that needs to be escaped:

```
var regex = /\*\*\*deal\*\*\*/g;
```

I've used a regex literal because that allows you to cut down on the number of backslashes; the equivalent using a regex constructor would be

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\*\\*\\*deal\\*\\*\\*', 'g');
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I've made it clear. I need to replace all occurences of `***deal***` the code above just returns the deal value

Comment: @SandeepBansal: The code above just constructs a regex. You still need to call the `replace()` method (as you did in your question).

Answer (score 1):

Special characters in Regular Expressions escaped by backslash `\`

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\*\\*\\*deal\\*\\*\\*', 'g');
```

in string values, you also need to escape `\` resulting `'\\'`